# Getting started with client -> server communication between two windows application. WCF?

Tags: .net, wcf

I've written an application that uses some serial port hardware directly, and abstracted the serial commands out into a object.

I'd like to use that object remotely from another application on another machine on the network, but I'm not sure where to start.  I previous used TCP and made up some commands to send over the network to control the object, but it's just to difficult to keep up and running, and feels like I'm re-inventing something I shouldn't have to.

I was looking at .net remoting, but it seems that is legacy now, and is being replaced by WCF.

All the WCF examples I have found seem like a replacement for a soap web service, and seem too restful for what I need.

The object I'm using has events that are fired when receiving data over the serial port, and a web based restful service doesn't seem to fit the bill.

Can someone point me the right direction?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yea, WCF is the best choice, [here](http://idesign.net/idesign/DesktopDefault.aspx?tabindex=5&tabid=11#Operations) you can find a huge db of WCF examples